# How to Seperate JSON data to display uniquely using Charts Library?

Tags: ios, charts, swift3, alamofire

I am able to Display JSON data to show Line Chart using Charts Library.I have Displayed all marks and Subjects but I am trying to Display in **TermWise**.How can be JSON Data be Seperated using TermID?

```
import UIKit
import Charts
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class ViewController: UIViewController , ChartViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menu: UIBarButtonItem!
    var login_details : Login?
    var markdetail : [Marks] = []
    var markd : Marks?
    var myResponse  :   JSON    =   nil
//    var Subjects: [String] = []
    var subjectss : [String] = []
    var marks01 : [Double] = []
    var setname = String()

    let Subjects = ["eng" , "sci", "math", "soc"]
    let marks1 = [45,55,70,80]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        menu.target = self.revealViewController()

        menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {

            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
        }

//        text.text = markd?.NAME

//        forlineView()
        getmarks()



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func getmarks(){
        let student_id = login_details?.masterid
        let std_id_String = student_id?.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9 ]", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range:nil)
        print("numberic",std_id_String!)

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://**********/api/academics//getSingleStudentsMarks"+"?StdID=" + std_id_String!)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON(){ response in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let data):
                print("success",data)

                let myresponse = JSON(data)
                for marks in myresponse.array!{
                    let marksObj = Marks(MarksJson: marks)
                    self.markdetail.append(marksObj)

                    self.subjectss.append(marksObj.CourseName)
                    self.marks01.append(marksObj.marks)
//                    for name in markdetail{
//                    
//                    }

                    self.setname.append(marksObj.examDescription)

                    print("Markss",marksObj.marks)
                    self.forlineView()
                    self.textdisplay()
                }


            case.failure(let error):
                print("Not Success",error)
            }

        }
    }


    func forlineView() {
        // 1
        self.lineChartView.delegate = self
        // 2
        self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "Tap node for details"
        // 3
        self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.textColor = UIColor.red
        self.lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
//        self.lineChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        // 4
        self.lineChartView.noDataText = "No data provided"
        // 5
        setChartData(subject: subjectss)

    }

    func setChartData(subject : [String]) {

        // 1 - creating an array of data entries
        var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()

        for i in 0..<subject.count {
            yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(marks01[i])))
        }

        // 2 - create a data set with our array
        let set1: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals1, label: setname)
        set1.axisDependency = .left // Line will correlate with left axis values
        set1.setColor(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)) // our line's opacity is 50%
        set1.setCircleColor(UIColor.red) // our circle will be dark red
        set1.lineWidth = 2.0
        set1.circleRadius = 6.0 // the radius of the node circle
        set1.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
        set1.fillColor = UIColor.red
        set1.highlightColor = UIColor.red
        set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true

        //3 - create an array to store our LineChartDataSets
        var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()
        dataSets.append(set1)

        //4 - pass our months in for our x-axis label value along with our dataSets
        let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        data.setValueTextColor(UIColor.red)

        //5 - finally set our data
        self.lineChartView.data = data

        //6 - add x-axis label
        let xaxis = self.lineChartView.xAxis
        xaxis.valueFormatter = MyXAxisFormatter(subject)

    }




    func textdisplay(){
        for d in self.markdetail{

            self.text.text = d.NAME

        }
    }


}

class MyXAxisFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    let subjectss: [String]

    init(_ subjects: [String]) {
        self.subjectss = subjects
    }

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return subjectss[Int(value) % subjectss.count]
    }

}
```

**currently i am getting**

[image]

**JSON**

```
 (
        {
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        CourseID = 4027;
        CourseName = Arts;
        Marks = 45;
        NAME = "Calvin Patterson";
        Sno = 2107;
        StdID = 95;
        TermID = 6022;
        "Terminal_FM" = 100;
        "Terminal_PM" = 40;
        "UT_FM" = 50;
        "UT_PM" = 20;
        examDescription = "First Term";
        type = Terminal;
    },
        {
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        CourseID = 5034;
        CourseName = Math;
        Marks = 90;
        NAME = "Calvin Patterson";
        Sno = 2108;
        StdID = 95;
        TermID = 6022;
        "Terminal_FM" = 100;
        "Terminal_PM" = 40;
        "UT_FM" = 50;
        "UT_PM" = 20;
        examDescription = "First Term";
        type = Terminal;
    },
        {
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        CourseID = 5035;
        CourseName = English;
        Marks = 52;
        NAME = "Calvin Patterson";
        Sno = 2109;
        StdID = 95;
        TermID = 6022;
        "Terminal_FM" = 100;
        "Terminal_PM" = 40;
        "UT_FM" = 50;
        "UT_PM" = 20;
        examDescription = "First Term";
        type = Terminal;
    },
        {
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        CourseID = 6034;
        CourseName = hi;
        Marks = 70;
        NAME = "Calvin Patterson";
        Sno = 2110;
        StdID = 95;
        TermID = 6022;
        "Terminal_FM" = 100;
        "Terminal_PM" = 40;
        "UT_FM" = 50;
        "UT_PM" = 20;
        examDescription = "First Term";
        type = Terminal;
    },
        {
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        CourseID = 4027;
        CourseName = Arts;
        Marks = 50;
        NAME = "Calvin Patterson";
        Sno = 4119;
        StdID = 95;
        TermID = 7024;
        "Terminal_FM" = 100;
        "Terminal_PM" = 40;
        "UT_FM" = 50;
        "UT_PM" = 20;
        examDescription = Second;
        type = Terminal;
    },
        {
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        CourseID = 5034;
        CourseName = Math;
        Marks = 60;
        NAME = "Calvin Patterson";
        Sno = 4120;
        StdID = 95;
        TermID = 7024;
        "Terminal_FM" = 100;
        "Terminal_PM" = 40;
        "UT_FM" = 50;
        "UT_PM" = 20;
        examDescription = Second;
        type = Terminal;
    },
        {
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        CourseID = 5035;
        CourseName = English;
        Marks = 70;
        NAME = "Calvin Patterson";
        Sno = 4121;
        StdID = 95;
        TermID = 7024;
        "Terminal_FM" = 100;
        "Terminal_PM" = 40;
        "UT_FM" = 50;
        "UT_PM" = 20;
        examDescription = Second;
        type = Terminal;
    },
        {
        CLASSNO = 1;
        "CLASS_ID" = 2021;
        CourseID = 6034;
        CourseName = hi;
        Marks = 80;
        NAME = "Calvin Patterson";
        Sno = 4122;
        StdID = 95;
        TermID = 7024;
        "Terminal_FM" = 100;
        "Terminal_PM" = 40;
        "UT_FM" = 50;
        "UT_PM" = 20;
        examDescription = Second;
        type = Terminal;
    }
)
```

**required**

[image]

> I have displayed all JSON Data in charts.I want to Display marks and
>   Subjects in TermWise .How it can be Done? I want to display marks and
>   subjects in first term and Second, these terms have same subjects but
>   marks are different and want to plot in same chart

**Model class**

```
class Marks {
    var classno = String()
    var class_id = String()
    var  course_id = String()
    var marks = Double()
    var Sno = String()
    var stdid = String()
    var TermID = String()
    var CourseName = String()
    var Terminal_FM = String()
    var Terminal_PM = String()
    var UT_FM = String()
    var UT_PM = String()
    var examDescription = String()
    var type =  String()
    var transferRate = String()
    var NAME = String()

    init(MarksJson:JSON) {
        self.classno = MarksJson["CLASSNO"].stringValue
        self.class_id = MarksJson["CLASS_ID"].stringValue
        self.course_id = MarksJson["CourseID"].stringValue
        self.marks = MarksJson["Marks"].double!
        self.Sno = MarksJson["Sno"].stringValue
        self.stdid = MarksJson["StdID"].stringValue
        self.TermID = MarksJson["TermID"].stringValue
        self.CourseName = MarksJson["CourseName"].stringValue
        self.Terminal_FM = MarksJson["Terminal_FM"].stringValue
        self.Terminal_PM = MarksJson["Terminal_PM"].stringValue
        self.UT_FM = MarksJson["UT_FM"].stringValue
        self.UT_PM = MarksJson["UT_PM"].stringValue
        self.examDescription = MarksJson["examDescription"].stringValue
        self.type =  MarksJson["type"].stringValue
        self.transferRate = MarksJson["transferRate"].stringValue
        self.NAME = MarksJson["NAME"].stringValue

    }


}
```

Comment: "Subjects in TermWise" Could you explain that? You mean to regroup notes of the same subject (all maths, all English, etc.)? If that's the case, you just have to sum the corresponding one, or do a average.

Comment: I have updated image and trying to display marks and subjects in termid wise to show different lines in charts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Change your code like this, 




     for marks in myresponse.array!
        {
        let marksObj = Marks(MarksJson: marks)
        if marksObj.examDescription == "First Term"
        {
        self.markdetail.append(marksObj)
        self.subjectss.append(marksObj.CourseName)
        self.marks01.append(marksObj.marks)
        self.setname = marksObj.examDescription
        print("Markss",marksObj.marks)
        self.forlineView(examDescription: marksObj.examDescription)
        self.textdisplay(marks: marksObj)
        }
        else if marksObj.examDescription == "Second Term"
        {
        self.markdetailForSecondTerm.append(marksObj)
        self.subjectssForSecondTerm.append(marksObj.CourseName)
        self.marks01ForSecondTerm.append(marksObj.marks)
        self.setname = marksObj.examDescription
        print("Markss",marksObj.marks)
        self.forlineView(examDescription: marksObj.examDescription)
        self.textdisplay(marks: marksObj)
        }
        }
    }

    func forlineView(examDescription: String)
    {
        if examDescription ==  "First Term"
        {
            // 1
            self.lineChartView.delegate = self
            // 2
            self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "Tap node for details"
            // 3
            self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.textColor = UIColor.red
            self.lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            //        self.lineChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            // 4
            self.lineChartView.noDataText = "No data provided"
            // 5
            setChartData(subject: subjectss,marks: marks01,exam: examDescription)
        }
        else if examDescription ==  "Second Term"
        {
            // 1
            self.lineChartView.delegate = self
            // 2
            self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "Tap node for details"
            // 3
            self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.textColor = UIColor.green
            self.lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            //        self.lineChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            // 4
            self.lineChartView.noDataText = "No data provided"
            // 5
            setChartData(subject: subjectssForSecondTerm,marks: marks01ForSecondTerm,exam: examDescription)
        }
    }

    func setChartData(subject : [String], marks : [Double], exam: String) {

    // 1 - creating an array of data entries
    var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    if (exam == "First Term")
    {

        for i in 0..<subject.count {
            yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(marks[i])))
        }
        // 2 - create a data set with our array
        let set1: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals1, label: "First Term")
        set1.axisDependency = .left // Line will correlate with left axis values
        set1.setColor(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)) // our line's opacity is 50%
        set1.setCircleColor(UIColor.red) // our circle will be dark red
        set1.lineWidth = 2.0
        set1.circleRadius = 6.0 // the radius of the node circle
        set1.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
        set1.fillColor = UIColor.red
        set1.highlightColor = UIColor.red
        set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true

        //3 - create an array to store our LineChartDataSets
        dataSets.append(set1)

        //4 - pass our months in for our x-axis label value along with our dataSets

    }

    else if (exam == "Second Term")
    {
        var yVals2 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<subject.count {
            yVals2.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(marks[i])))
        }
        // 2 - create a data set with our array
        let set2: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals2, label: "Second Term")
        set2.axisDependency = .left // Line will correlate with left axis values
        set2.setColor(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)) // our line's opacity is 50%
        set2.setCircleColor(UIColor.red) // our circle will be dark red
        set2.lineWidth = 2.0
        set2.circleRadius = 6.0 // the radius of the node circle
        set2.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
        set2.fillColor = UIColor.red
        set2.highlightColor = UIColor.red
        set2.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true

        //3 - create an array to store our LineChartDataSets
        dataSets.append(set2)


    }

    let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    data.setValueTextColor(UIColor.red)

    //5 - finally set our data
    self.lineChartView.data = data

    //6 - add x-axis label
    let xaxis = self.lineChartView.xAxis
    xaxis.valueFormatter = MyXAxisFormatter(subject)

}

    func textdisplay(markDetails: [Marks]){
        for d in self.markDetails{

            self.text.text = d.NAME

        }
    }
```

Comment: i am getting same result as mine previous screen shot

Comment: or do we need to change any in **setChartData**

Comment: yes i am trying like that both terms marks should be displayed in different lines

Comment: i have created model classes n updated it above , is it good or do i need to create another model class and how to separate NSMutableArrays for each terms

Comment: i have created it already so i was appending **Marks** data in array strings

Comment: ya  i created and what to do now

Comment: i had updated my answer , please check it above ....... Create three arrays like this and then use above code... `var markdetailForSecondTerm : [Marks] = []
var subjectssForSecondTerm : [String] = []
var marks01ForSecondTerm : [Double] = []`

Comment: sorry for late reply cause i was out of mac and its giving me an error in "index out of range" in this line "yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(marks[i])))"

Comment: i got marks like this in array s [45.0]
s [45.0, 90.0]
s [45.0, 90.0]
s [45.0, 90.0, 52.0]
s [45.0, 90.0, 52.0]
s [45.0, 90.0, 52.0]
s [45.0, 90.0, 52.0, 70.0]
s [45.0, 90.0, 52.0, 70.0]
s [45.0, 90.0, 52.0, 70.0]
s [45.0, 90.0, 52.0, 70.0]
s [50.0]
s [50.0]

Comment: i have managed error but its showing me only second term marks line

Comment: or mine JSON api data is wrong to display multiple lines in chart view

Comment: Create a separate IBOutlet for `lineChartView` like     `@IBOutlet weak var lineChartViewForSecondTerm: LineChartView!`
 for second term marks and use it wherever second term marks are listed....... UR JSON is correct, no problem with it.

Comment: you mean to create another lineChartview for second term ??

Comment: Yes , exactly,.

Comment: but i need to display both marks in same linechart like i have in  required images at above isn't it possible through this JSON api Sir , and Thanks a lot for your help and suggetions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445428/multiple-line-chart-dont-want-to-plot-0-values-swift-2.... Follow this link.

Comment: ya i have watched it and how can be this done in my case code , n i'm trying too

Comment: `var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()` Declare this line above ViewDidLoad and follow my corrected answer

Comment: ya its display now both records and that color indication is giving me array data i will update image above why that setname is repating so many times ?

Comment: i have uploaded

Comment: i have uploaded image now it its showing array data but not previously type

Comment: Cannot able to get u,, what is the problem now,,,

Comment: that color indication lable should be only 1 first term and 2 second term they are repeating like first term are 4 and second is 8 and in required image there color indication is 1/1 only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148590/discussion-between-bikesh-thakur-and-vignesh-davins).

Comment: have u found the solution for multiple terms